# BCP skips some rows while generating csv file in bat

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Assume t1 and t2 are 2 tables , when I run sql query in microsoft sql studio , it generates k rows ,

```
 select * from t1 join t2 on t1.colA = t2.colA where t1.colB like 'ab%'
```

but the same query when run through bcp generates n rows always less than k . What is wrong with the query in bcp ?

```
 set DEST = C:\Users\userA\Desktop\exports
 set BCPARGS =-c -t, -S <servername> -d <dbname> -U user1 -P passwd1 -e %DEST %errors.txt
 bcp "select * from t1 join t2 on t1.colA = t2.colA where t1.colB like 'ab%'" queryout %DEST %csvname.csv  %BCPARGS %
```

Comment: I don't think anyone could do anything but guess here without some sample data (preferably the "failed" row examples).

Comment: I echo  erros to errors.txt , but found no errors  and also tried putting parameter to bcp command to fail even if 1 error occurs , so that error goes to errors.txt file

Comment: Well if there were no errors then I am guessing it's a data problem...

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know the fact that % is used to indicate a replaceable parameter in windows based terminal (cmd) .
So, **%%** should be used in like part of sql query i.e **like 'ab%%'** instead of **like 'ab%'**

The first % indicates that the second % is part of a name rather than a replacable parameter just like escape sequence.